# How to create a gap between rows in CSS

Tags: css

****please note that Momin's comment below (CSS flexbox and gap could be ideal solutions for you! developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap –
Momin) was the solution that worked for me - thanks****

I would like to know how I can create a gap between my two rows without it creating a 'double gap' in mobile. At the moment I've added a < br tag between the rows in the html. And this works fine in desktop view. But when I view it in mobile, it creates a sort of double gap between the third and fourth 'cards'. Does anyone know of another solution to this? I've tried fiddling with row-gap, but that did nothing (I'm not even sure it's appropriate in this case since this is not a grid).

If I remove the BR break, there is no space between the rows and the 'buttons' touch each other in desktop. If I then add a margin-bottom to the row class in the css, the touching rows problem is fixed in desktop, but I still have the 'double space' problem in mobile.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
<div class="card">Get a<br />
part-time job</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
<div class="card">Join a club<br />
or society</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
<div class="card">Find out<br />
about volunteering</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="row">
<div class="column2">
<div class="card">Participate in<br />
Melbourne Plus activities</div>
</div>

<div class="column2">
<div class="card">Explore the LMS</div>
</div>
</div>



 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Float 3 columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 0 10px;

}

/* Float 2 columns side by side */
.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
/* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding in columns */
.row {margin: 0 -5px;}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Style the counter cards */
.card {
  /* this adds the "card" effect */
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
border-top: 4px solid #ee8889;

}

.card:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* this adds the "card" effect */
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
border: 3px solid #ee8889;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Responsive columns - one column layout (vertical) on small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
gap-row: 10px;

  }
.column2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you,
Maria[image: desktop view gap ok]

[image: mobile view 'double gap']

Comment: CSS `flexbox` and `gap` could be ideal solutions for you!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

Comment: Note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Thank you Momin - that worked perfectly. Flexbox with gap of 10px. Now it all looks the same in desktop and mobile!

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late but if you look at your html you added a break, and then in your css you used margin-bottom. So between using the break and margin-bottom you created two spaces. Delete the break in your html between the two row divs, then adjust margins top/bottom to fit your expectations.

Comment: Thanks Dalton. You're not late! I should have clarified that what was happening without the break was that i was getting no space between the rows in desktop ie. the 'buttons' in each row were touching each other. When I remove the break and add a margin-bottom of 20px to the row class, then I have a space between the rows in desktop, which is good! But I still have the 'double space ' problem in mobile.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th {
            background-color:green;
            Color:white;
        }
        th, td {
            width:150px;
            text-align:center;
            border:1px solid black;
            padding:5px
        
         }
        .geeks {
            border-right:hidden;
        }
        .gfg {
            border-collapse:separate;
            border-spacing:0 15px;
        }
        h1 {
            color:green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <h1>GeeksforGeeks</h1>
    <h2>Row spacing in a table</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class = "gfg">
        <tr>
            <td class = "geeks">10001</td>
            <td>Thomas</td>
            <td>M</td>
            <td>32</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "geeks">10002</td>
            <td>Sally</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </center>
</body>
```

You can try this code and let me know if this works or not.

Comment: You can try above code

Comment: The `<center>` element has been marked [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for at least 10 years. Do not use that.

Comment: Thank you Ekansh, I'm loathe to use tables for accessibility reasons